# MySQL Result Set - No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java, jdbc

I can't figure out what this error means or how to fix it. I'm trying to retrieve some data from one of my databases but keep running into this error message below.

```
preparedStatement = connect
            .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mydatabase "
                        + " WHERE TickerID=?");
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); //where it says the error is, line 132
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                aIDTA = resultSet.getInt("AccountID");
                nameTA = resultSet.getString("Name");
                CashBalance = resultSet.getDouble("CashBalance");
                TradeFeeBuy = resultSet.getDouble("TradeFeeBuy");
                TradeFeeSell = resultSet.getDouble("TradeFeeSell");
                AssetsBalance = resultSet.getDouble("AssetsBalance");
            }



Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2261)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2191)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2004)
    at BuyAndSell.BuyAndSell(BuyAndSell.java:132)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

Comment: You are missing the parameter, the error message also says this very clearly. You have no parameter set, google the error to solve this kind of questions...

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5, but the string length is 4, not 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287160/java-sql-sqlexception-no-value-specified-for-parameter-5-but-the-string-length)

Comment: @NoaNoNym Although that question has the same error, it is not an exact duplicate: in that question the user also tried to parametrize the objectnames

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to fill parameter in `PreparedStatement`

```
preparedStatement.setLong(1, someIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is maybe because you didn't set parameter for your request:

```
SELECT * FROM mydatabase WHERE TickerID= ?
```

You have to add:

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "youUserIdValue");
```

Before to execute the query.

You can also use named parameter:

```
preparedStatement = connect
        .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mydatabase "
                    + " WHERE TickerID=:userID");
preparedStatement.setString("userID", "youUserIdValue");
```

Comment: JDBC doesn't have named parameters, although vendor specific implementations might have this, so your second example won't work through the standard `java.sql.PreparedStatement` interface